# How do I translate relationships (that have attributes) into relational schema/sql?

Tags: sql, database

I am relatively new to database design.

I've recently learnt that relationships in EER can possess attributes, and thus, have constructed the following entities.

LibraryMembers
(memberID)

Books
(bookID)

The two entities are connected through the relationship "reserve", each book able to be reserved by 0 to 1 LibraryMember, and each LibraryMember being able to reserve 0 to many books.

Now, here comes the problem. I have assigned attributes such as time and date to the "reserve" relationship, and I have no idea how to translate this into relational schema. The relationship between LibraryMembers and Books is not a many to many, is it still possible to create a table called "reserve" to link them?

(I've been taught that an additional table is only created when the relationship maps from a many to many EER)

Help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you should deffinatly use a mapping table between libraryMember and Books (also for historical reasons - meaning, this book has been gone for... X times). That a Book can't be lent twice should not be the task of the schema (maybe a trigger/procedure, but at best at application layer). So I reccommend using 3 Tables to get this done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map members and books in reservations like this

```
CREATE TABLE members(
member_id INT,
member_name VARCHAR(64),
PRIMARY KEY(member_id)
);

CREATE TABLE books(
book_id INT,
title VARCHAR(64),
PRIMARY KEY(book_id)
);

CREATE TABLE reservations(
reservation_id INT,
book_id INT,
member_id INT,
reservation_date DATETIME,
PRIMARY KEY(reservation_id),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books (book_id),
CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (member_id) REFERENCES members (member_id)
);
```

But you still need to implement logic that prevents a book to be reserved twice at the same time as @Najzero commented.

Comment: Much thanks to both of you for clearing this up! I suppose I can make use of a trigger to prevent a book from being reserved twice?